# Create records in two models by Nested serializer with two foreign keys pointing same model in Django

Tags: django, nested, foreign-keys, serialization, drf-writable-nested

Make two records on the same table Department by foreingn key relation using nested serializer. 
,this Department two records are creating at same time the People table created

```
class Department(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class People(BaseModel):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='teacher')
    student = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='student')
    available_seats = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = '__all__'

class PeopleSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    teacher = DepartmentSerializer(many=True, write_only=True)
    student = DepartmentSerializer(many=True, write_only=True)
    available_seats = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = People
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here I need to accept this input and create records in People and Department table

### Input

```
{

    "available_seats":100,
    "teacher": [{
            "name": John,
            "age" : 37
        }],
    "student": [{
            "name": John,
            "age" : 37
        }]
}
```

But i am getting this error
 "Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use student.set() instead."

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove many_True

```
class PeopleSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    teacher = DepartmentSerializer(write_only=True)
    student = DepartmentSerializer(write_only=True)
```